# ngCookies returns undefined for existing cookie

Tags: angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

I've been scratching my head for this one for hours now yet still haven't found the cause or solution.

Basically I have an Angular.js frontend that tries to log users in (with `ngCookies` on Angular.js 1.3.15) by communicating with an authentication API endpoint in the backend. Upon success, my code should redirect the user to another page.

So the login code looks something like:

```
auth.login($scope.user).success(function() {
  $state.go('overview');
});
```

where `auth` is a service that has a `login` method which simply sends an POST request to the backend. `$state.go('overview')` will do the redirect. This code should be ok as I get HTTP200 back from the server given I supply the correct user credentials. However, the browser won't redirect me to the overview page because it still thinks I'm not logged in unless I refresh the page.

The code that checks if the current user is logged in uses a helper method called `getToken()`, where I use `ngCookies` to retrieve a cookie named `USER_SESSION`. And this method is where I think the problem is.

The method itself is simply

```
auth.getToken = function() {
  return $cookies.USER_SESSION;
};
```

However it always returns `undefined` even when the `USER_SESSION` cookie exists in the browser.

Some testing I did (on a remote testing server so accessing cookies in `localhost` shouldn't be a concern):

```
auth.getToken = function() {
  console.log($cookies);
  console.log($cookies.USER_SESSION);
  return $cookies.USER_SESSION;
}
```

The results of `console.log`:

```
// Before login:
Object {...} // No USER_SESSION, this is good
undefined

// After hitting the login button, browser sends AJAX request,
// server returns HTTP200 response with Set-Cookie in the header:
Object {USER_SESSION: ""aa21fcd..."", ...} // UESR_SESSION exists, good
undefined // ???

// After refreshing the page:
Object {USER_SESSION: ""09b4tk..."", ...}
"09b4tk..."
```

Are the double quotes the problem here? I thought so initially, but after refreshing the page, `$cookies` returns the same thing (same double quotes but a different `USER_SESSION` value) and `$cookies.USER_SESSION` would have the correct value, and user would be on the overview page.

Does this mean `Set-Cookie` in the HTTP response header needs a page refresh to take effect?

Thanks!

P.S. Same problem occurs with `cookieStore`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and i couldn't address that with ngCookies. I decided to use the local storage instead.

I use this module:
https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

And also, based on the code you showed, local storage will be a better fit for you app.
See: [Local Storage vs Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies)

Comment: Thanks, I switched to jquery-cookie and things worked. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

It's because the interface has changed. You need to use .get() and .set() with $cookies now.

```
    $cookies.set('USER_SESSION', 'your value here');

    auth.getToken = function() {
        return $cookies.get('USER_SESSION');
    }
```

Comment: .set() is not a method of the $cookie service. I thin you mean .put()?

Answer (score 0):

So, I've been wrestling with this for about a day or two as well, because I was working on a login cookie. Examples I used where done with `$cookieStore`, which is naturally deprecated now, so I quickly switched over to `$cookies`, thinking that's that.

Well, here's the thing. When you're using `$cookies`, it's important to note that there's a difference between `$cookies.put` and `$cookies.putObject`. The same applies to `$cookies.get` and `$cookies.getObject`, naturally.

I foolishly thought that my object would work anyway, but no, turns out that's how I ended up getting the `undefined`.

Now, for your question, I'm going to assume that `'USER_SESSION'` is an object, and therefore you're running into this issue. Otherwise, you don't seem to have used a .put() or .get() either. So try this for now.

```
//if your cookie is an object

$cookies.putObject('USER_SESSION', cookieObject)

auth.getToken = function() {
    return $cookies.getObject('USER_SESSION');
}


//if your cookie is not an object

$cookies.put('USER_SESSION', 'cookie')

auth.getToken = function() {
    return $cookies.get('USER_SESSION');
}
```